# Unable to list the consumer groups from remote kafka cluster

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

We have a remote kafka cluster which has multiple brokers. It has SSL & Jaas configuration setup for authentication. I have installed kafka in my local windows 10 system, and I am trying to connect to this remote kafka cluster to run the consumer & producer batch commands.
Now, I am able to get the list of topics from the remote cluster, also can create new topics but unable to list the consumer groups, it is showing error,

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server {kafka-broker-1}:9093 --command-config config/consumer.properties --list
```

`Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to find brokers to send ListGroups.`

Comment: Can you share the command you're running?

Comment: And you haven't setup any SSL or JAAS settings for that command? Or what is part of `conflg/consumer.properties`? Please [edit] your question with this information

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes all the necessary properties are setup in the consumer.properties as I am able to produce and consume messages from topic in remote cluster. It is only that I am unable to use the kafka-consumer-groups.bat command

Comment: Well, that command uses the `AdminClient` where the consumer and producer scripts do not, so you might be missing properties to configure the admin client, which are not shared with the consumer client properties. It would still be useful if you could edit your question to show that property file

Comment: Have you tried to run something like `set KAFKA_OPTS="-
Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/kafka_client_jaas.conf` before running the kafka scripts?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I am using that jaas config inside the consumer.properties, as mentioned above, `sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{usrname}" password="{pswrd}"; ` ..............do i need to separately have the kafka_client_jaas.conf file, in that case what will be its content? And i am using windows machine

Comment: The `-Djava.security...` flag is for the whole JVM that is started by the CLI script, so both would be necessary, I think... JAAS files are just plaintext, and you can find examples here - https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/